# Two back buttons appearing whilst using NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a project I am working on. I have minimised the project to show the layered views for the purpose of this question.

The project displays ShoeRowView in a ScrollView. The ShowRowView features a Button titled "See All". This button takes the user to ShoeSeeAllView. This is where there is a VStack listing all the different pairs of shoes in the form of a view called ShoeViewLong.

When a ShowViewLong is tapped, it takes the user to ShoeDetailView.

The Navigation works as expected but the issue is there are two back buttons, one under the other.

I have tried using an @State var with @Binding but can't seem to get anything to work.

Here is the code:

```
struct Marketplace: View {
   
    var body: some View {
               
        NavigationView {
            MarketplaceShoesView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct MarketplaceShoesView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {            
            ShoeRowView(shoeData: shoe)
                        
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ShoeRowView: View {
            
    @State private var isShowingDetailView = false
    var shoeData: ShoeRow
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                
                Text(shoeData.title)
                            
                HStack {
                    
                    NavigationLink("", isActive: $isShowingDetailView){ShoesSeeAllView(shoeData: shoeData, shoe_id: shoeData.id)}
                        .navigationTitle("")

                    Button("See All") {
                        isShowingDetailView = true
                    }
                                         
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
 
                }
                .padding(.trailing)
            }
                        
            HStack {
                                
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        
                        ForEach(shoeData.shoes ?? []) { shoe in
                            
                            Text("Name of shoes")

                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            Divider()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ShoeSeeAllView: View {

    var shoeData: ShoeStruct
    var shoe_id: String

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                
                VStack {
                    VStack(spacing: 25) {
                        
                        ForEach(shoeData.shoes ?? []) { shoe in
                            
                            ShoeViewLong(shoeData: shoe)
                            
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(shoeData.title)
    }
}
```

```
struct ShoeViewLong: View {

    var shoeData: ShoeStruct

    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: ShoeDetailView(shoe_id: shoeData.id ?? "")) {
           
            HStack(spacing: 12){
                      
                Image("ShoeImage")
                    .resizable()
               
                Text("Shoes Name")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ShoeDetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is shoes detail view")
    }
}
```

How can I fix the Navigation? It should go like this:

Tap "See All" (in a ShoesRowView) -> ShoesSeeAllView -> Tap a ShoeViewLong -> Take to ShoeDetailView.

When in ShoeDetailView, the user taps back button -> goes to ShoesSeeAllView > Tap back again -> goes to MarketplaceShoesView (where ShoeRowView is being displayed)

Comment: It is because you have nested `NavigationView`s, remove the extra `NavigationView` from `ShoeSeeAllView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with nested NavigationView's. After removing NavigationView from ShoeSeeAllView, the problem was solved.